# Does zetteldeft miss some org-roam functionality?

Tags: org-roam

Has somebody used both packages and could tell me whether zetteldeft misses some functionality of org-roam? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

First off: I’m the author of Zetteldeft. And second: I don’t think this is a question of the ‘factual’ type that can be adequately answered in the StackExchange format. That said: Zetteldeft and Org-roam are two completely different packages, with different aims and philosophies. Zetteldeft is rather minimalist and relies on Deft. It supports and facilitates linking between notes but doesn’t do much to automate such tasks

But to answer your y-or-n question: yes, Zetteldeft lacks a lot of Org-roam functionality

Comment: Not really an answer, but to get an idea of what Zetteldeft is about, I suggest cloning the `zd-tutorial` to check out Zetteldeft from within Zetteldeft: https://github.com/EFLS/zd-tutorial